# How to make my select autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, select, autocomplete

I have this function which fill the Select list

```
 function filldropdownlistDemandUnitsEmployee(res) {
            var select = document.getElementById("#drpRequestDemandUnit");
            $("#drpRequestDemandUnit").empty();
            $('#drpRequestDemandUnit').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", -1).text('الكل'));
            if (res != null) {
                var test = $.parseJSON(res.d);

                $(test).each(function () {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', this.UserId).text(this.NameAr);
                    $("#drpRequestDemandUnit").append(option);
                });
            }
            var valuee = $("#drpRequestDemandUnit").val();

            $("#<%= hiddenFieldDemandEmployeeID.ClientID %>").val(valuee);
        }
```

I need to make it support auto completion
I try this

```
 $("#drpRequestDemandUnit").autocomplete({

             select: function (event, ui) {
                 $("#drpRequestDemandUnit").val(ui.item.text);
                               return false;
             }
         });
```

but I got nothing because I don't know how to get the source

please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it incorrectly, follow this [example here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) if you want the select box to transform to autocomplete, otherwise usually autocomplete is done over text boxes, and here is how you do it, click run and type in the text box to verify

```js
 function loadList(res) {
   var options = ['الكل'];
   if (res != null) {
     var test = $.parseJSON(res.d);

     $(test).each(function(i, d) {
       options.push(d);
     });
   }
   return options;
 }

 var myList = loadList({
   d: '[ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme" ]'
 });

 $("#auto").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
     console.log(myList);
     response(myList.filter(function(l) {
       return l.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) === 0;
     }));
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="auto" value="" />
```

Comment: How can I deal it with my code which written in a question body ?because I have a dynamic list not a static one

Comment: i've updated my answer to match your request as close as i could